# Calculate sum of values overlapping with another dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes as follows

```
depth
chr  Pos Nucleotide Coverage
chr1 1   A          10
chr1 2   G          12
chr1 3   T          3
chr1 4   A          20
chr1 5   T          22
chr1 6   N          0
chr1 7   N          0
chr2 23  A          1
chr2 24  T          5
chr2 25  G          15
```

and another dataframe of intervals

```
intervals

chr1  3  5
chr2 23 25
chr4  1 30
```

My desired output is as follows: if there are positions in the `depth` dataframe falling within the range as indicated in the `intervals` dataframe with the same `chr` value, the `Coverage` sum over all nucleotides is calculated for that range and assigned to the 4th column.

```
chr1  3  5 45
chr2 23 25 21
chr4  1 30  0
```

and

```
chr1 3   T  3
chr1 4   A 20
chr1 5   T 22
chr2 23  A  1
chr2 24  T  5
chr2 25  G 15
```

How can I create these two dataframes using R. I have very large files for depth dataframe with size of 50GB.

Comment: Why is the sum 0 for the range 1 to 30 but >0 for the sub-range 23 to 25? And what column is being summed?

Comment: And why is the interval 1 to 30 excluded from the second output?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan The Coverage column of the depth dataframe is being summed. The sum for chr4 1 30 is 0 because there is no overlapping value in the depth dataframe.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I wish to include the chr4 range positions in the second output as well.

Comment: Oh, missed the fact that `chr` was part of the join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sqldf`

```
library(sqldf)

out1 <- sqldf('
select    i.*
          , coalesce(sum(d.Coverage), 0) as CovSum
from      intervals i
          left join depth d
            on  d.Pos between i.low and i.high
                and d.chr = i.chr
group by  i.chr, i.low, i.high
')
out1        
#    chr low high CovSum
# 1 chr1   3    5     45
# 2 chr2  23   25     21
# 3 chr4   1   30      0

out2 <- sqldf('
select    d.*
from      intervals i
          join depth d
            on  d.Pos between i.low and i.high
                and d.chr = i.chr
')
out2
#    chr Pos Nucleotide Coverage
# 1 chr1   3          T        3
# 2 chr1   4          A       20
# 3 chr1   5          T       22
# 4 chr2  23          A        1
# 5 chr2  24          T        5
# 6 chr2  25          G       15
```

Data used

```
library(data.table)

depth <- fread('
chr  Pos Nucleotide Coverage
chr1 1   A          10
chr1 2   G          12
chr1 3   T          3
chr1 4   A          20
chr1 5   T          22
chr1 6   N          0
chr1 7   N          0
chr2 23  A          1
chr2 24  T          5
chr2 25  G          15
')

intervals <- fread('
chr   low high
chr1  3  5
chr2 23 25
chr4  1 30
')
```

Comment: I suppose that does address the issue of what to do when one or both of the objects will not fit into RAM.

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` works great for these kinds of operations:

```
# first, read in the data, with headers
depth <- read.table(header = T, text = 
"chr  Pos Nucleotide Coverage
chr1 1   A          10
chr1 2   G          12
chr1 3   T          3
chr1 4   A          20
chr1 5   T          22
chr1 6   N          0
chr1 7   N          0
chr2 23  A          1
chr2 24  T          5
chr2 25  G          15")

intervals <- read.table(header = T, text =
"chr  start   end
chr1  3  5
chr2 23 25
chr4  1 30")
```

Now you can get to work:

```
library(dplyr)
# create a new data.frame:
# link intervals with any rows from depth where the value of 'chr' matches
# (keeping all rows from intervals)

merged <-
  merge(intervals, depth, by = 'chr', all.x = T) %>%

  mutate(
    # add a column to flag rows in the range spec'd by intervals
    in_range = Pos >= start & Pos <= end,
    # substitute 0 for any missing values in Coverage
    Coverage = coalesce(Coverage, 0L))

# now you can get your results:

result1 <- 
  merged %>% 
  # keep those in range or with no value from depth$Pos
  filter(in_range | is.na(Pos)) %>%
  group_by(chr, start, end) %>%
  summarise(sum_cov = sum(Coverage))

result2 <-
  merged %>%
  # keep those in range
  filter(in_range ==T) %>%
  # only get the columns that were in depth
  select(names(depth))
```

The results are as you expect:

```
> result1
  chr   start   end sum_cov
1 chr1      3     5      45
2 chr2     23    25      21
3 chr4      1    30       0

> result2
   chr Pos Nucleotide Coverage
1 chr1   3          T        3
2 chr1   4          A       20
3 chr1   5          T       22
4 chr2  23          A        1
5 chr2  24          T        5
6 chr2  25          G       15
```

Comment: Who's downvoting this answer? :/